# Kali boot - gma500 trying to get vblank count for disabled pipe

Tags: boot, kali-linux

I just finished installing Kali Linux on a laptop (asus Eee PC 1101HA).
During boot, I'm stuck at this error:

> gma500 trying to get vblank count for disabled pipe.

If anyone had the same problem, and fixed it please reply.

Answer (score -1):

I am using a ASUS Aspire One (AO751h) with the same problem, this was my solution after many trial and errors so maybe it will work for you as well.  I found that the gma500 line is only a warning and the issue can be worked around by installing SLiM (Simple Login Manager).

First, boot into Recovery Mode from the GRUB and login as root.  Next make sure there is an Ethernet connection by typing in ping google.com, if not follow these instructions:

https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/forum/ethernet-isnt-working-kali-linux-recovery-mode-0158782/

Once there is a connection type the following commands, it can take a while for the updates

> apt-get update
>
> apt-get upgrade
>
> apt-get install slim

You will be asked to choose a display manager, be sure to choose "slim"

The login screen is the Debian rather than Kali screen but the username/password is the same.  I hope this solves your issue as well.